# String length() vs. char array strlen

Tags: c++

I am capturing the payload of a network packet. The payload is in `string` form. Then I convert that `string` into `char array`. Now, I want to calculate the size of each packet payload

```
string payload;
payload = raw_payload->GetStringPayload();
char input[payload.length()];
strcpy(input,payload.c_str());
int size;
size=strlen(input);
LOGfile_length <<  size << " " << payload.length()  << endl;
```

When I print the size of the packet payloads, it comes different for `string` payload and `char array` payload. Why is this so?

```
140 1448
71 1448
67 1448
0 6
0 6
0 6
0 63
```

Now , I am doing this

```
memcpy ( input,  payload.c_str(), strlen(payload.c_str())+1 );
```

but still the sizes of the packets come different

Comment: Does your string contain a null character?

Comment: @Namfuak That's the most likely cause.  But his code does depend on a compiler specific extension (a variable used for the length of a local C-style array) and undefined behavior (if he ever actually does copy all of `payload` into `input`).

Comment: But yes, strcpy WILL stop after first \0. I suggest using memcpy here if You REALLY want to move to plain C objects :)

Aghh, I see. 

Yes, `char input[dynamic()]` is absolutely incorrect.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Got it, it's because C++ array length should be an ICE and also if he copies all of it, the `\0` will go beyond the length of the array.

Comment: @Arenim: where the "absolutely" will be relativated by the and of the year...

Comment: Yes, `memcpy` will help - but also using `payload.length()+1` consistently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strcpy` and `strlen` will stop as soon as they encounter a NUL (zero byte) in the input. NULs are very likely to appear in the middle of network packet data, which means you won't see any of the packet data after the first NUL.

A working approach would be to use `string::length()` and `memcpy`:

```
string payload = raw_payload->GetStringPayload();
char input[payload.length()];
size_t size = payload.length();
memcpy(input, payload.c_str(), size);
LOGfile_length << size << " " << payload.length() << endl;
```

Answer (score 4):

Change the code to

```
char input[payload.length()+1];
```

This is because the the payload.length will return the number of characters in the string. We need one more byte to store the '\0' character.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Vaild point, but that's not it. You can see that the `strlen` value is always smaller, hence the `\0` never gets placed outside of the buffer.

Comment: Does C++11 support variable length arrays?

Comment: Network packets should not be considered as text since they are arrays of `uint8_t`.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews In that case what should I do? as I have to do some text analysis on packet payload dats.

Comment: @Zara: Try using `memcpy` for the text without the nul or apply the nul and count it as one of the packet bytes.

Comment: +1, while this is may not be the answer to the specific question, it fixes one of the bugs in the question and whether I would not upvote as the *answer*, having a negative vote count seems also wrong.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I did this memcpy ( input,  payload.c_str(), strlen(payload.c_str())+1 ); but still the sizes come different.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: The question was "why do I see the discrepancy in size" not "please review my code and find all mistakes". As such the answer is useless to the OP regarding his question.

Comment: @PlasmaHH: Say the other issue is fixed, the test is rerun. Will the discrepancy be gone? would it show a discrepancy on the other direction? Been there, done that, a few times. The issue is fixed, a different (maybe) related issue comes back and the question keeps being updated and it becomes confusing as there are different problems and each answer tackles one of them...

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: That is in no way a reason to encourage leaving the original OP question unanswered. It is good as an addition, but it doesn't allow the OP to move forward at all. (nor any people that search for and find this question and don't have the additional mistakes and are disappointed by not finding it answered; I somehow have the feeling that SO should be a kind of DB for QA that people other than the OP can use if they have the same Q). If this is meant as an addition to other questions, then imho it should say so, but as long as it doesn't it should answer the OPs question

Comment: @PlasmaHH: People searching and hitting a question "String length() vs. char array strlen" might be concerned about both type of issues. I agree that SO is a DB for answers (whole duplicate mechanism is for exactly that), but I find it harsh to greet a newcomer with negative votes when the answer is not incorrect, but is not complete.

Comment: This is just not a useful answer. The OP's current approach of trying to store arbitrary binary data in a char[] using `strcpy` and `strlen` is not valid, and trying to paper over that with this change is not productive. If storing the data in plain C structures is required, using `memcpy` and tracking the size in a separate variable is the way to go.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Where are you going to draw the line? The answer is useless for the OP to proceed with his current problem. Are answers that are missing the real problem, but point out bad style, or spelling errors ok too? That suggest clearly superior alternatives with parts of the code unrelated to the problem? As the OP I would think "This answer not useful to me". And then read the downvote button hover text.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect this is because Your payload contains `\0` characters.

You can easily check it with this code:

```
for(int i=0; i<payload.length(); i++) printf("%d\n", payload.c_str()[i]);
```

or, to make output shorter (thanks to Agent_L),

```
for(int i=0; i<payload.length(); i++) 
  if(payload.c_str()[i]==0) 
    printf("Found \\0 at %d\n", i);
```

and if You see 0 signs there -- You have bytearrays which can not be fit into plain-C strings.

P.S. and shintoZ is right too.

Comment: Network packets are best considered as an array of bytes or `uint8_t` and not text strings.  Text strings need a terminating nul.

Comment: "which can not be fit into plain-C strings" is quite a bad wording here. You can put null bytes just fine there, the reason is that `strlen` interprets them as terminators, thus returning a different lenght of the string than expected.

Comment: Well, You can use `char*` to store these objects, but you SHOULD NOT call them "strings" and should not use methods from `string.h` on it :).  `memcpy` - OK, `strcpy` - not.

Comment: I'd add `if(payload.c_str()[i]==0)`, just to save OP from manually inspecting 1448 bytes : )

Comment: @ I used memcpy but seems the results are again the same. Please help me what else I can do becuase in the end I need the packet payload in char array form.

Comment: @Arenim: While they are not necessarily strings, you can use `strcpy` and `strlen` on them, as long as you have the null terminating byte. Now, if you have more than one null-terminating byte, well that's a problem.

Comment: @Zara Indeed they're the same! Because if You've even copied all the memory, strlen will stop after first `\0`.

You just jave to submit that there is no way to get length of `char*`, you should store it in another variable

Comment: @Arenim Can you pleasee provide me the code for this purpose.

Comment: @Zara Sure! `int length = payload.length(); `. Only the PAIR of (input) and (length) will be a living entity.

Comment: This answer does not provide a way to find the size of the string unfortunately.

Comment: @Arenim I am a bit confused. Can u please clear me. DO u mean something like this? memcpy ( input,  payload.c_str(), payload.length());

Comment: @Zara NO. Again: there is absolutely no way to get length of plain C pointer. You CAN NOT use strlen/strcpy/any string function because Your data contains `\0` characters. You have only way to store your bytearray (i don't call it 'string') length in other variable.

Comment: @Arenim Do u mean the payload as byte array? After keeping its length in other variable then afterwards what should I do??